# Argonaut decoder how to change the type of one value in a case class

Tags: scala, argonaut

Id like to use the `casecodecN` or shapeless decoder for my case class, but one the fields has a different type when it is json.

consider, where `b` in json is a String like `"1.23"`, but I want it as a Double.

```
case class Foo(a: Double, b: Double)
```

If I use casecodec2 it will error because `b` is a string

```
casecodec2(Foo.apply, Foo.unapply)("a", "b")
```

So I must manually write `DecodeJson`

```
DecodeJson[Foo](
  c =>
    for {
      a <- (c --\ "a").as[Double]
      b <- (c --\ "b").as[String].map(_.toDouble)
    } yield Foo(a, b)
)
```

This is ok for short case classes, but is tedious for bigger ones.

Is there a way I case use a derived Decoder but change just one values type ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use an implicit convertion inside your class:

```
case class Foo(a: Double, b: Double){
   implicit def string2Double(s: String): Double = augmentString(s).toDouble
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good option. However If I do that its not clear which field can have string doubles. I still want it to be a decoding failure if `a` is formatted that way.